# PHP Cannot open/read CSV file from URL whereas I can open/read it from localhost. What's wrong?

Tags: php, csv

Using php I am trying to get some data from a .csv file which is stored online (www.website.com/data/my_file.csv). While testing the code on localhost (using xampp) everything works great, but when I moved my files to my online server it doesn't work.
What i am doing is:

```
$filesize=2000;
$handle = fopen("www.website.com/data/my_file.csv", "r") or die ('cannot open the file');
$raw = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);
```

this will give me '*cannot open the file*'. If I try the same code from localhost, it works.
Furthermore, I tried this other way:

```
$filesize=2000;
$handle = fopen("my_file.csv", "r") or die ('cannot open the file');
$raw = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);
```

which actually works, but the problem is that the .csv file should be open/read from the full url.
Is there anything that I am overlooking or this is just the wrong way of doing it?

Comment: The http wrapper needs the protocol on the front as in `http://www.website.com/data/my_file.csv`

Comment: did you try using http scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on a shared hosting account of some sort? A lot of those places don't allow remote calls by disabling the allow_url_fopen directive.

Try running this at the beginning of your file:

```
<?php
   ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.
@ ajacian81 - your solution did not solved the problem but it guided me to the solution. I am in a shared hosting so they have disabled allow_url_fopen directive. So, the solution was to get a new php.ini and put it into the directory where I am calling my file from ('..data/my_file.csv'), and it's working.

Comment: @Augerto glad it's working for you at least.  Shared hosting can be a pain sometimes :).

Answer (score 1):

It may be security issue. I would try to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
$csv = file_get_contents("www.website.com/data/my_file.csv");
// limit maximum length
$csv = file_get_contents("www.website.com/data/my_file.csv", false, null, 0, $filesize);
```

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a
>   file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported
>   by your OS to enhance performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fopen('http://www.website.com/data/my_file.csv','r')` after making sure that [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled.